# Hibernate @Version not updating

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities Product and Order, Whenever I create an order, I update the order_id of the product (foreign key). I am trying to apply optimistic locking, so that in the process of fetching a product for checking if it's orderId is null and then updating the orderId with the new orderId, no other threads go through. How can I ensure that via @Transaction and @Version?
Even the update query is n't changing the version.
Should I make any schema changes for the versioning to work?

Order Repository

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("Update ProductEntity p set p.orderId = :orderId " +
            "where p.productId = :productId")
    void updateProductByOrderId(Long orderId, Long productId);
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
// @Table
public class ProductEntity {

    public ProductEntity(String brandName, double price) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long productId;

    @Column
    private String brandName;

    @Column
    private Double price;

    @Nullable
    @Column(name = "fk_order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;
```

```
@Transactional
    public OrderEntity createOrder(OrderReq orderReqBody) throws Exception {
        List<ProductEntity> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long id : orderReqBody.getProductIdList()) {
            ProductEntity productEntity = this.productRepository.findById(id).get();
            if (productEntity.getOrderId() != null) {
                throw new Exception("one or more product(s) are unavailable");
            }
            productList.add(productEntity);
        }
        
        OrderEntity toSave = OrderEntity.builder()
                .amount(orderReqBody.getAmount())
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .build();
        OrderEntity orderEntityDB = this.orderRepository.saveAndFlush(toSave);
        for (ProductEntity p : productList) {
            this.productRepository.updateProductByOrderId(orderEntityDB.getOrderId(), p.getProductId());
        // i am attaching a debuggger at this line and 
running an update query via workbench, 
still the version remains the same and both are able to update.

        return orderEntityDB;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that your Query isn't updating the Version column; you aren't setting it in the update query.  You can add logic to increment the version in the query, but I recommend a different approach.

Since you already have a list of product entities you retrieved in the method, modify your for-loop to update the entity's orderId and save the entity directly.

```
for (ProductEntity p : productList) {
   p.setOrderId(orderEntityDB.getOrderId());
   productRepository.save(p);
}
```

Comment: It works, but if i want he version to be updated on every update query via SQL workbench, how can I achieve that? one approach is by setting version explicitly. Can it be achieved by hibernate, that it sets some metdata by default?

Comment: ```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("Update ProductEntity p set p.orderId = :orderId, p.version = (:version + 1) " +
            "where p.productId = :productId and p.version = :version")
    int updateProductByOrderId(Long orderId, Long productId, Long version);

this helped, but save() was much easier